# MathJax preview during editing does not work

Tags: bug, status-norepro, markdown-preview, mathjax

When editing [particular post at stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/62543/5509), the MathJax preview does not show - it only shows the latex code. When editing other posts it does show.

I tried in Firefox  22.0 and Opera 10.

Comment: What browser and OS are you using?

Comment: I tried several different browsers of different versions; I guess the problem will be somewhere else. @Oded or it doesn't happen to you?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Using latest Chrome on Windows 7 - going to your link and clicking edit shows the correct preview. Nor can I repro with FireFox.

Comment: @Oded, Chrome is the only browser for which it works for me.

Comment: I just tried Opera as well. Editing the link, changing the expression and back shows the formatted formula as expected.

Comment: When editing, are you getting JavaScript errors? Try clearing the cache and refreshing.

Comment: @Oded, no javascript errors. Cleaning cache didn't help

Comment: Can you check on the network tab of the developer tools if all resources are downloading OK? Is there anything that isn't getting through? (just wondering if some files are blocked)

Comment: No errors in the Network tab.

Answer (score 1):

The edit preview seems to be working just fine for me (on Chrome 28, Win):

[image]